# Google Search Console Crawl 404 Error for some wp-content directories even when those directories contain files

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, web-crawlers, robots.txt, 404

Here is a picture of my Google Search Console:

[image: Search console 404 errors]]

When I try to click at the url for example error 18: `wp-content/uploads/2016/01/` 
Appear File not found.

[image: File not found]

Of course inside the path (`wp-content/uploads/2016/01/`) I have a lot of pictures. 
And when I type `example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image1.png` I can see the image.

This is my robots.txt file if can help anywhere or should I change anything:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 30
```

Can anyone explain why this type of errors occurred. (`wp-content/`) 
And if there is a solution?

-------- EDIT --------

Only 3 out of 9 are linked 
For example:

```
1. wp-content/uploads/2013/07/
is linked to: example.com/attachment-sitemap.xml

2. wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ 
is linked to: example.com/post-sitemap1.xml and /attachment-sitemap.xml

3. wp-content/uploads/2015/07/ 
is linked to: example.com/post-sitemap3.xml
```

The rest 6 are not liked with anything

```
1. wp-content/uploads/ 
2. wp-content/uploads/2012/08...    Why are these three dots in the end?
3. wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ 
4. wp-content/uploads/2016/10/ 
5. wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ 
6. wp-content/uploads/2015/01/
```

All of them when I go at the URL, it shows: File not Found.
Is there a correct way to fix it so that it does not appear as errors in google search console?

Comment: Might be those 6 URL is included in your old sitemap which is generated by some other plugins. From where the remain 6 URL is linked, is it from same sitemap URL?

Comment: @Goyllo 
I have indexed /sitemap_index.xml
No 6 URLs are not from the same sitemap URL.
The /2012/08 is from /post-sitemap1.xml
The /2015/12/ is from /post-sitemap3.xml
The /2016/10/ is from /post-sitemap4.xml etc... 
That is what you asked for? I would appreciate any help, I am a little lost.
Thank you!

Comment: There is one possibility: Suppose in 2012 or 2015, you have installed one sitemap plugin and it generated those URL's by mistake and on that time Google try to fetch it, because it is included in your sitemap, but after sometimes plugin developer fix that issue in his/her next version, but Google still trying to index that file, because when you display 404 error then Googlebot will come back with time to time in hope that, those pages will be live in future, but if you return 410 error then it indicate to Googlebot that, those pages are permanently gone, so stop fetching it now.

Comment: You can simply ignore those errors, sometimes you've to understand why google search console display the error. Those errors are helpful when you've some important pages on your site and then you changed it's URL, that time you've to fix those pages with 301 redirection, but here it is only directory, and it is not linked from your other site pages(Instead it is from sitemap) so there is no loss of pagerank, anchor text and search traffic, so you can simply ignore it. *Number of errors does not impact in ranking, the type of error, and what causes it is most important.*

Answer (score 1):

You have disabled viewing of the folder, which means the folder itself is returning a 404 status. This is generally a good move as it stops people sniffing around trying to find out what files you have on your server.

Google for some reason has decided to check those folder URLs. Maybe you have something linking to them, or Googlebot inferred that they exist by mistake.

If you click on one of them a window will show which may have a Linked from tab. Click on that to see how Googlebot found those URLs.

Otherwise, don't worry. You are telling Googlebot exactly what it should be told.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I made an addition to my question to make it more detailed.
I'm glad to see your opinion.

Comment: Google could have found those folders at any time in the past. ... in a URL often indicates some dumb scraper site tried to link to your website, and got it wrong. Even when the links have gone, Google will remember them. You can mark them as fixed, which should hide them for a while or even forever. Remember, this is a none issue, telling Google they do not exist is the right thing to do.

Comment: I had tried 2 weeks ago to mark them as fixed, and they reappeared.
If it were a page or a post it would be more clear to me, now it's a folder that has in-images.
What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: They are not an issue outside you see them reported, and they can get in the way of real issue. A hack, but you could set up redirects to say the home page. It should stop them being reported in that report that you are concerned about. It's not the right thing to do (which is nothing), but it resolves your concern.